# Which regularizer to use to get a sparse set of regression parameters?

Tags: regression, regularization

I am doing a regression and I want to use the regularizer that will be the most useful to get a sparse set of parameters.

Which regularizer should I use ? Cardinality? maximum value ? Sum of absolute values ? Euclidean norm ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common sparse regularizer is **sum of absolute values** (so-called Lasso regression). With carefully chosen penalty coefficient, it makes some of less useful parameters exactly zero.

**Cardinality** penalty exactly imposes sparsity, but it cannot be combined with gradient descent, and usually requires combinatorial optimization. Simply put, it is slow to apply.

**Maximum value** and **Euclidean norm** do not affect sparsity at all.

You can find more details in the [wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)#Regularizers_for_sparsity) article.